# 'You must declare "ids" as a unique array of fields in your source settings'

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to learn about importing images with migrations using this tutorial and this custom module (c11n_module). When I install and try to run 'drush ms' I keep getting an error.

```
In CSV.php line 105: You must declare "ids" as a unique array of fields in your source settings.
```

The id looks like this:

```
keys:
  - ID
```

The helper thought I found shows this:

```
ids: 
  id:
    type: integer
```

However, if I change to this:

```
ids: 
  keys:
    - ID
```

I still get the error. I have spent a few hours trying to figure this out. I am assuming it is in the YML file that I have to correct this. Any ideas for solving this issue?

Or am I thinking about it all wrong?

Here is the whole YML:

```
# Migration file for creating "image" for academic programs.
#
# Detailed explanations for various elements of a migration
# YAML have been provided in migrate_plus.migration.program_data.yml

id: program_image
label: Image associated to academic programs.
migration_group: c11n
migration_tags:
  - academic program
  - file
  - image
# Source.
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://import/program/program.data.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids: 
    keys:
      - Image file
  # Source field definitions.
  fields:
    Image file: Name of the image file associated with the program.
  constants:
    file_source_uri: public://import/program
    file_dest_uri: 'public://program/image'
# Destination.
destination:
  # We will be creating entities of type "file" this time.
  plugin: 'entity:file'
# Mappings.
process:
  file_source:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_source_uri
        - Image file
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  file_dest:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_dest_uri
        - Image file
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  filename: Image file
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@file_source'
      - '@file_dest'
# Dependencies.
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - c11n_migrate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it doesn't look familiar, with `keys` and the way the `fields` are mapped; might just be it's a method I haven't come across though.

Either way I've always had success processing CSVs like this:

```
ids:
  - image_file
fields:
  0:
    name: image_file
    label: Image file
```

That assumes the first column in the CSV contains the unique image file name.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is exactly what I needed. Still learning yaml and figure it out. Thanks Clive !